# Removal of storage prefix from database

Tags: migration, try-runtime

I am currently writing a migration to remove a pallet and all its memory from our runtime. Unfortunately, I cannot manage to check for the existence of the pallet's prefix in the pre- and post upgrade `try-runtime` hooks as all of my tried check function return false, even if the storage exists, e.g. `frame_support::storage::unhashed::kill_prefix(&prefix, None)` returns `AllRemoved(5)`.

I have tried the following functions which internally use `sp_io::storage` API:

```rust
frame_support::storage::unhashed::exists(&prefix);
frame_support::storage::get_raw::exists(&prefix);
frame_support::storage::migration::have_storage_value(&prefix, &[]);
frame_support::storage::migration::have_storage_value(&prefix, &some_storage_entry);
```

Moreover, after removing all entries with `kill_prefix` in the `on_runtime_upgrade_hook`, the same call results in `SomeRemaining(1)` when checking in `post_upgrade` hook. Does this happen because one storage entry persists in the in-memory overlay of the `try-runtime` execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the frame support iterators on pallet maps when available could be the better approach.

If not using frame support (or storage structure do not allow iteration), one can use sp_io primitives (similar to support raw api).
First check existence of prefix key, then call `sp_io::storage::next_key(prefix)` until the resulting key does no start with the prefix.
That's pretty low level but does not need to assume anything from the pallet (just its prefix and that it never did write outside of it).

`kill_prefix` always apply from the prefix (there is no persistence of previous calls progress), so it only make sense to call it multiple time if the limit of removed items is increased (generally calling it only once per block is better).