# Proper removal of Substrate Pallet, including storage / prefix

Tags: pallet

There are a few other questions related to this topic:

1. [removal of storage prefix](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/removal-of-storage-prefix-from-database)
2. [clearing the storage](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/506/forked-parity-pallet-didnt-migrate-storage-deployed-to-chain-how-to-clear-or)

In terms of functions related to these actions, I found the following:

1. remove_storage_prefix
2. kill_storage
3. kill_prefix

Also, I wanted to note that the overall goal is to upgrade from v2.0.1 to v3.0.

What would be the best way to remove an existing pallet from the storage?
Do we have to kill_storage first, and then kill_prefix?

Comment: As the chain state goes larger and larger, it gets hard to export/fetch the chain state. Are there any other tools aside from fork-off-substrate and try-runtime for performing a runtime migration? runtime

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of how FRAME generates storage keys leads to the fact that all pallets have their storage under a shared prefix-trie:

[image]

All the storage keys are in the format:

```
hash(name) ++ hash(name) ++ hash(name) ++ ...
```

For example:

```
twox128(pallet_name) + twox128(storage_name) + ...
```

So if you call `remove_storage_prefix` or `kill_prefix` with the appropriate pallet prefix, you will remove all the storage for that pallet.

Comment: What if I use `move_prefix` (move a large pallet to a new prefix)?
Is that an O(1) operation?

Comment: No. None of these operations would be `O(1)`. You need to remove or move all items in the database under this prefix, which will be `O(n * log(n))`. It is VERY expensive.